# Imputing the date and time in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having a data set like below and I am trying to impute the value like below.

```
ID    In                      Out
4   2019-09-20 21:57:22       NA
4   NA                    2019-09-21 5:07:03
```

When there NA's in lead and lag for each ID's, I am trying to impute the time to cut off the previous day and start new time for the next day. I was doing like this, but I am getting error

```
  df1%>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(In= ifelse(is.na(In) & is.na(lag(Out)),
                        as.POSIXct(as.character(paste(as.Date(In),"05:00:01"))),
                        In)) %>%
  mutate(Out= ifelse(is.na(Out) & lead(In) == "05:00:01",
                       as.POSIXct(as.character(paste(as.Date(Out),"05:00:00"))),
                       Out))
```

The desired output will be

```
ID    In                      Out
4   2019-09-20 21:57:22   2019-09-21 05:00:00
4   2019-09-21 5:00:01    2019-09-21 5:07:03
```

Dput for the data

```
structure(list(concat = c("176 - 2019-09-20", "176 - 2019-09-20", 
"176 - 2019-09-20", "176 - 2019-09-20", "176 - 2019-09-21"), 
    ENTRY = structure(c(1568989081, 1569008386, 1569016635, 1569016646, 
    NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), EXIT = structure(c(1569005439, 
    1569014914, 1569016645, NA, 1569042433), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000007e21ef0>)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Do you want to automate the process or reference at 5 am only? Can you also provide a bigger reproducible example? Thanks

Comment: Not to automate. The reference is just to cut the time of previous day at 5AM and start the next day at 5:00:01 AM

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the desired output by separating the date and time and pasting it back. Definitely this is not a efficient way to achieve this. May be some one can suggest other efficient way to do this which gives some learning at least.

```
df%>%
  mutate(ENTRY_date = as.Date(ENTRY)) %>%
  mutate(EXIT_date = as.Date(EXIT))%>%
  mutate(ENTRY_time = format(ENTRY,"%H:%M:%S"))%>%
  mutate(EXIT_time = format(EXIT,"%H:%M:%S"))%>%
  mutate(Entry_date1 = if_else(is.na(ENTRY_date)&is.na(lag(EXIT_date)),EXIT_date,ENTRY_date))%>%
  mutate(Exit_date1 = if_else(is.na(EXIT_date)& is.na(lead(ENTRY_date)),ENTRY_date,EXIT_date))%>%
  mutate(Entry_time1 = if_else(is.na(ENTRY_time)&is.na(lag(EXIT_time)),"05:00:01",ENTRY_time))%>%
  mutate(Exit_time1 = if_else(is.na(EXIT_time)& is.na(lead(ENTRY_time)),"04:59:59",EXIT_time))%>%
  mutate(ENTRY1 = as.POSIXct(paste(Entry_date1, Entry_time1), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))%>%
  mutate(EXIT1 = as.POSIXct(paste(Exit_date1, Exit_time1), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, using your `dput()` data did not work for me.  Anyway, if I understand your question correctly you can do it like this:

```
# load pacakge
library(lubridate)
# replace missing In values with the corresponding Out values,
# setting 5:00:01 as time.
df$In[is.na(df$In)] <- ymd_hms(paste0(as.Date(df$Out[is.na(df$In)]), " 5:00:01"))
# same idea but first we save it as a vector...
Out <- ymd_hms(paste0(as.Date(df$In[is.na(df$Out)]), " 5:00:00"))
# ... then we add one day
day(Out) <- day(Out) + 1; df$Out[is.na(df$Out)] <- Out
```

This works for the data that you provided but if Out time is 2019-09-21 04:07:03, for example, then the correstponding In time is *later*, namely 2019-09-21 05:00:01. I do not know if this is intended. If not please specify your question.

I used this data

```
structure(list(In = structure(c(1569016642, NA), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Out = structure(c(NA, 1569042423), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), .Names = c("In", "Out"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```